# Can anyone help me to optimize this for loop use SSE?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, sse

I have a for loop which will run many times, and will cost a lot of time:

```
for (int z=0; z<temp; z++)
{
    float findex= a + b * A[z];
    int iindex = findex ;
    outArray[z] += inArray[iindex] + (findex - iindex) * (inArray[iindex+1] - inArray[iindex]);
    a++;
}
```

I have optimized this code, but have no performance improvement! Maybe my SSE code is bad, can any one help me?

Comment: Can you tell us anything about what does it do? What is A? Did you check at the assembly output?

Comment: changing `z++` to `++z` usually is a good idea too

Comment: @user2485710: Why would that make any difference here?

Comment: I'm not sure I see much vectorization opportunity here; you're not processing contiguous memory, in general.

Comment: you are right, so I think I must use "_mm_set_ps" many times to generate __m128 data

Comment: I suppose by the time code get to `outArray[z] += ...`, `findex` no longer equals `iindex`, else you have `outArray[z] += inArray[iindex];`

Comment: @chux - one is `float`, the other is `int`. This is an interpolation routine of sorts.

Comment: Make sure `a` is a `float` - it will save you a type conversion in every loop (and you could do `float findex = a++ + b * A[z];` but the compiler probably took care of that already.) If `b * A[z]` is always between 0 and 1 you can set `index = a` and save a bit more time (probably cheaper to increment an int and a float in each loop than to convert one to the other).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `restrict` keyword on inArray and outArray. Otherwise the compiler has to assume that `inArray` could be ==  `outArray`. In this case no parallelization would be possible.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply! I have use multithread outside the for loop, so I think there is no need to use parallelization. The original program is a little complex, so I have simplified the for loop.I want to use simd to optimize the loop. May be there will be performance imorove with sse!

Comment: Using "restrict" keyword will help compiler to disambiguate inArray and outArray, and thus automatically or semi-automatically vectorize the loop. (and I guess Kay meant instruction-level-parallelization - i.e. vectorization).  But 1.disambiguation is not sufficient to efficiently vectorize the loop. As others mentioned below, you also have to 2. solve cross-iteration dependency and 3. think of unit-stride (contiguous) memory access. Once you're done with it - Compiler should be able to auto-vectorize (for Intel Compiler you can also try #pragma simd or # pragma ivdep)

Answer (score 3):

Your loop has a loop carried dependency when you write to `outArray[z]`.  Your CPU can do more than one floating point sum at once but with your current loop you only allows one sum of `outArray[z]`.  To fix this you should unroll your loop.

```
for (int z=0; z<temp; z+=2) {
    float findex_v1 = a + b * A[z];
    int iindex_v1 = findex_v1;  
    outArray[z] += inArray[iindex_v1] + (findex_v1 - iindex_v1) * (inArray[iindex_v1+1] - inArray[iindex_v1]);

    float findex_v2 = (a+1) + b * A[z+1];
    int iindex_v2 = findex_v2;
    outArray[z+1] += inArray[iindex_v2] + (findex_v2 - iindex_v2) * (inArray[iindex_v2+1] - inArray[iindex_v2]);
    a+=2;
}
```

In terms of SIMD the problem is that you have to gather non-contiguous data when you access `inArray[iindex_v1]`.  AVX2 has some gather instructions but I have not tried them.  Otherwise it may be best to do the gather without SIMD.  All the operations accessing `z` access contiguous memory so that part is easy.  Psuedo-code (without unrolling) would look something like this

```
int indexa[4];
float inArraya[4];
float dinArraya[4];
int4 a4 = a + float4(0,1,2,3);
for (int z=0; z<temp; z+=4) {
    //use SSE for contiguous memory
    float4 findex4 = a4 + b * float4.load(&A[z]);
    int4 iindex4 = truncate_to_int(findex4);

    //don't use SSE for non-contiguous memory
    iindex4.store(indexa);      
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        inArraya[i] = inArray[indexa[i]];
        dinArraya[i] = inArray[indexa[i+1]] - inArray[indexa[i]];
    }
    //loading from and array right after writing to it causes a CPU stall
    float4 inArraya4 = float4.load(inArraya); 
    float4 dinArraya4 = float4.load(dinArraya);

    //back to SSE   
    float4 outArray4 = float4.load(&outarray[z]);   
    outArray4 += inArray4 + (findex4 - iindex4)*dinArray4;
    outArray4.store(&outArray[z]);
    a4+=4;      
}
```